# Tunnel ---------ngrok.io not found

Tags: ngrok

I am trying out [Hidden Eye](https://github.com/DarkSecDevelopers/HiddenEye) from GitHub as a test with my friends.

[Hidden Eye](https://github.com/DarkSecDevelopers/HiddenEye) works like this:
1. It makes a fake login page.
2. Uses ngrok to forward this to the people outside your network.

When my friend does it, it works but when I ask him to run for example 2107f2ac.ngrok.io it says Tunnel 79cd0b59.ngrok.io not found.

I have restarted, reinstalled and done everything under the moon.

I thought that ngrok passes firewalls but my only guess is maybe my firewall is blocking it so I added a firewall exception of the ngrok port but it still does not work.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

The generated link is online as long as your terminal/shell is open once you generate link and turn terminal off then it won't work. So if you close your terminal you need to regenerate new link.

Comment: Perfect Answer !!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and here is the **solution**: The ngrok system fails many times when the user is not authenticated, I recommend that you log in to the official **ngrok web**, create an account, follow all the steps indicated in the page and it should work fine for you, I did that and solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I might be really late, but I came up with the same problem a few days ago, and solved it, the problem I had was that first my tunnel didn't work at all and after that only in local host, but I figured it is because I was using a virtual machine, so Use a dual boot and this should solve the problems, I have encountered a lot of people that says Virtual machines have a lot of bugs with different tools.

Mauricio